# Listen event when scroll is added in texterea on Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some texterea.
`Height : 100px`, `width : 200px` .
I want to listen event when scroll is added

```
<textarea class="txt" style="height:100px;width:200px">
</textarea>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var element=document.getElementsByClassName('txt')[0];
if (element.clientHeight < element.scrollHeight) {

    //has scrollbar

} else {

    //doesn't have scrollbar

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (($(".txt").css("overflow"))) {
   // your code
}
```